# Is it okay to ask questions with a generic tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I am planning to publish [an open source project](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon) based on Spring Framework. The users of that project would be Spring application developers. As Spring uses SO as its support forum, I think it might be convenient for the users if my project uses SO as well, for the *how-to* kind of question/answers. I understand [SO's policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support), and plan to use SO according. But I don't have enough reputation to create a tag. So, I was wondering how about telling my users to ask questions with the generic [spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring) or [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag initially, till I have a 1500 reputation.

Like to know how does this sound.

Comment: It's not about wrong or right, but Spring tag gets a lot of questions. If you publish it on Github, you can use their forums directly for support issues, and people ask the developers directly on Github which I think is more beneficial.

Comment: Yes, it's on GitHub. But as I know, unfortunately GitHub does not have a forum.

Comment: They have some way where users can contact the developer.

Comment: "unfortunately GitHub does not have a forum" - Stack Exchange is not a forum either.

Comment: Please do not do this until you at least know how stackoverflow works. Review the [help], [ask], [answer], and most importantly: http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Comment: David, my selection of the word "forum" might be wrong. I meant the exact thing which we do here for Spring developers under the "spring-*" tags, i.e. responding to how to questions etc.

Comment: I don't understand why so many downvotes. Many opensource projects are already using SO, and I would definitely be abiding by the rules (http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)

Comment: Downvotes on meta.stackoverflow mean people disagree with the proposal or think the answer is "no", not that they didn't like your question.

Comment: I see! Thanks for clarifying. I am mostly a StackOverflow user, and there downvote seems to imply that people didn't like your question, AFAIK. Many people might be falling into this confusion, then.

Answer (score 10):

The best thing to do is not to use Stack Overflow as a support forum.

Comment: But don't many projects, like Spring, do it?

Comment: @Sanjay Read this *very* carefully :  Stack Overflow can never be the sole support venue for a product http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Comment: Right. I was planning to use SkackOverflow only for the how-to kind of things. For issues etc. GitHub issue system would be great. For other things like discussing features, I could create a google forum, if the GitHub issue system would not suffice, I'm thinking.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with using SO as your support forum is that inevitably you'll get questions that would be decidedly on-topic for a normal support forum but are decidedly *off topic* for SO. This means that you deny your users support for certain issues, essentially.

This is why you need another avenue where people can request support and file things that would be very off topic for SO, like bug reports.

It is not a good idea to solely rely on SO as your support forum.